# php get positive random response in a prize contest

Tags: php, mysql, random

I was trying to design a contest where after user registration, the web page shows a button to play the game. By pressing the button, the page returns "you win" or "sorry, no win".

The problem is, how to give to the positive results less chances to be shown and not the 50/50. Say, it would be nice to have a 1 win out of 10 games.

I have set a mysql table for the user attempts. Every user has one chance only to play.

I cannot figure out the randomness mathematically speaking...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rand()` and then check for a specific result

```
select (cast(rand() * 10 as unsigned)) = 1
```

Step by step:

```
select rand()                                 returns a number between 0.0 and 1.0
select cast((rand() * 10) as unsigned)        returns a number between 0 and 9
select cast((rand() * 10) as unsigned) = 1    checks if the result was 1 which is a win
                                              but it is a loose for all random numbers != 1
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. I'll give a try. It could be the right path

Comment: that was perfect. I have tested it a few times and it works great. Thank you very much